# How to animate a balloon filling with air

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to display a balloon picture on the iphone and a button on top when we tap the button the balloon starts filling.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QuartzCore2D shape objects to create the ballon.

or you can have a ballon image in the view of small size and then increase the dimensions of it when the button is pressed to make it look like the ballon is filling with air.

But use QuartzCore2D to make it look realistic.